# Combine picture and plot with matplotlib with alpha channel

Tags: python, image, matplotlib

I have a .png image with alpha channel and a random pattern generated with numpy.
I want to supperpose both images using matplotlib. The bottom image must be the random pattern and over this, I want to see the second image (attached in the end of the post).

The code for both images is the following:

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.cm as cm

# Random image pattern
fig = plt.subplots(figsize = (20,4))

x = np.arange(0,2000,1)
y = np.arange(0,284,1)
X,Y = np.meshgrid(x,y)
Z = 0.6+0.1*np.random.rand(284,2000)
Z[0,0] = 0
Z[1,1] = 1

# Plot the density map using nearest-neighbor interpolation
plt.pcolormesh(X,Y,Z,cmap = cm.gray)
```

The result is the following image:

[image]

To import the image, I use the following code:

```
# Sample data
fig = plt.subplots(figsize = (20,4))

# Plot the density map using nearest-neighbor interpolation
plt.imread("good_image_2.png")
plt.imshow(img)
print(img.shape)
```

The image is the following:

[image]

Thus, the final result that I want is:

[image]

Comment: You need to merge both images first, then use matplotlib to plot the merged image. Otherwise you will get some artifacts all over the place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make an image-like array for **Z** and then just use **imshow** to display it before the image of the buttons, etc. Note that this only works because your png has an alpha channel.

Code:

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.cm as cm

# Plot the density map using nearest-neighbor interpolation
img = plt.imread("image.png")
(xSize, ySize, cSize) = img.shape
x = np.arange(0,xSize,1)
y = np.arange(0,ySize,1)
X,Y = np.meshgrid(x,y)
Z = 0.6+0.1*np.random.rand(xSize,ySize)
Z[0,0] = 0
Z[1,1] = 1

# We need Z to have red, blue and green channels
# For a greyscale image these are all the same
Z=np.repeat(Z,3).reshape(xSize,ySize,3)


fig = plt.figure(figsize=(20,8))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.imshow(Z, interpolation=None)
ax.imshow(img, interpolation=None)

fig.savefig('output.png')
```

Output:
[image]

You can also turn off axes if you prefer.

```
ax.axis('off')
```

[image]